# Cast and reference in one line

Tags: c

Check the code:

```
void mem_set( void** mem_input, void** mem_current )
{
    *mem_input = *mem_current;
    ...
}

main()
{
    ...
    void* mem_pos = ...;
    float* cb_p = ...;

    void* temp = (void*)cb_p;
    mem_set( ( &temp, &mem_pos ); // works, but clumsy         
}
```

I would like to avoid having to create and populate a temporary variable when calling `mem_set`(because I have many `mem_set` calls). Can the call somehow be done in one line?

`mem_set( ( &( (void*)cb_p ), &mem_pos )` doesn't work.

p.s.
Please advise a better title for the question.

Comment: Maybe it's wrong, but can you try this:
mem_set(((void**)(&cb_p)), &mem_pos)

Comment: You shoud never cast to or from `void *` in C language...

Comment: @SergeBallesta what's your rationale? In fact, that's what `void*` is used for. You wouldn't be able to perform a simple `malloc` without (implicitly) casting from `void*` to your destination pointer type.

Comment: A `float*` will happily degrade into `void*`, but I doubt that `float**` will degrade into a `void**`

Comment: @andreee `int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));` compiles just fine in C

Comment: Yes, and it _implicitly_ casts the returned `void*` to `int*`. I agree that _explicit_ casts shouldn't be done, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @andreee no, it *converts* implicitly. Casts are always explicit

Comment: @SergeBallesta I thought arguments for `%p` in printf have to be cast to `void*`?

Comment: @andreee - There are no implicit casts. A cast is an explicit *conversion*. You are right that there is an implicit conversion here. As is Serge

Comment: Okay, agree. Never took notice of the distinction between cast and conversion in this context. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: In the first place, why do you need your `mem_set` function? Just for the purpose of assigning a pointer? If you have any `void*` pointer, you can simply assign any other object pointer to it. You should not hide such a basic operation in a function and let the compiler do its job.

Comment: @JensGustedt It's more than that, just not shown here for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware when using temporaries!

This will not change the value of `cb_p`:

```
void* temp = (void*)cb_p;
mem_set( &temp, &mem_pos ); // works, but clumsy
```

Because temp is a different pointer that initially points at the same object as `cb_p` does. So `mem_set` only changes the value of `temp` and leaves `cb_p` untouched.

That also means that this (otherwise fully standard conformant) solution does not change `cb_p` either:

```
mem_set( &(void*){&cb_p}, &mem_pos );
```

`&(void*){&cb_p}` creates a temporary `void *` pointer, here again initialized with the *value* of `cb_p` and only the temporay is changed by `mem_set`.

Demo code:

```
float f1 = 1., f2 = 2.;
void* mem_pos = &f2;
float* cb_p = &f1;

//void* temp = (void*)cb_p;
mem_set(&(void*){&cb_p}, &mem_pos ); // works, but clumsy         

printf("%f\n", *cb_p);
```

outputs

```
1.000000
```

If you want to change `cb_p`, you have to pass its own address:

```
mem_set((void**)&cb_p, &mem_pos );
```

With this line, above demo outputs `2.000000`.

The only implementation dependant feature required here is that pointers to any type shall have same alignment and representation. `mem_pos` is a `void *` that was initialized from a `float *`. So it can legally be casted back to a `float *` and will receive the original value.

`cb_p` is a `float *` and `&cb` if a `float **`. The cast causes a conversion to a `void **`. Next the pointed value receives another pointer value. Here it is required that `void*` and `float*` do have same representation, and this point is not guaranteed by the standard but it is true in all implementations I know: a pointer is no more than the memory address of the first byte of an object (*).

If this point is allowed by the implementation, `cb_p` has been assigned the value of a `void *` that was initialized from a `float *`. Here again provided all pointers have same representation, `cb_p` current representation is the representation of a pointer to a float object: `cb_p` points to that object.

---

(*) Unfortunately, draft n1570 for C11 says in 6.2.6.1 General

> 1 The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.

and the subclause does not state anything for pointers representation

Comment: Good point. I kinda focused on the OP's comment `// works, but clumsy` and figured they actually have working code they want to refactor.

Comment: My bad: should have said "compiles, but clumsy". I was sure it would work. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Casting `&cb_p` is ill-advised. A `float**` and a `void**` are not compatible pointer types. The assumption that "all pointers are the same" need not hold in general.

You can however do something that almost looks like a cast, but isn't one. You can use a compound literal. That expression creates an lvalue, unlike the regular value a cast produces. And you can take the address of an lvalue:

```
mem_set( &(void*){cb_p}, &mem_pos );
```

`(void*){cb_p}` produces an unnamed void pointer (this is the compound literal expression), which is initialized from `cb_p`. And since it's an lvalue, the address can be legally taken. That will avoid the named temporary as you wish.

Just make certain that your compiler supports [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) or later.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - True. I guess it depends on how much the OP's example is illustrative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mem_set (  (void **)&cb_p, &mem_pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the syntax for casting in C is.

```
(type)value
```

Here your value is `&cb_p` and type is `void**` not the `void*`

```
mem_set ( (void**)&cb_p, &mem_pos );
```